# Why does Apple require podcasts to use both new-feed-url and a redirect?

Tags: itunes, podcast

Why does Apple require podcasts to use both [`<itunes:new-feed-url>`](https://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#newfeed) tag and a redirect? It seems like a redirect gives the exact same information with less data required. What should a podcast client's behavior be when the Location header and the tag's value differ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current best guess:

iTunes wants to allow podcast owners to make redirects part of the actual fetching process. For instance, my podcast's feed url could be

`http://example.com/crawl/step1`

If that would redirect to `/crawl/step2`, and iTunes considered a redirect the same as a feed move, it would never go to `/crawl/step1` again.

But with the tag, redirects can be part of the crawling process.